# Trigger To Check new employees dont already exist

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers, oracle-apex

I am trying to create a trigger to check if an employee already exists in my emp_mb table and i get this error message

ORA-00969: missing ON keyword

Any Ideas ?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER adduser_mb
BEFORE 
INSERT OR UPDATE emp_id 
ON emp_mb
FOR EACH ROW 
DECLARE 
DUMMY INTEGER;
BEGIN 
     SELECT COUNT(*) INTO DUMMY 
     FROM emp_mb 
     WHERE emp_id = :new.emp_id

     IF (dummy > 0) 
        THEN raise_application_error(-20501 
        'Employee ID' || :new.emp_id || ' already exists');
END IF;
END;
```

Comment: Why don't you use a unique constraint or a primary key?

Answer (score 8):

You can't realistically do this in a single (non-compound) trigger.

A row-level trigger on `emp_mb` cannot generally query `emp_mb`.  Once you solve the syntax issue, you'll get a mutating table exception.

The proper way to ensure that the `emp_id` is unique is to create a unique constraint on the table.

```
alter table emp_mb
  add( constraint uk_emp_id unique (emp_id) );
```

If you really, really, really wanted to do this with triggers, you'd need multiple triggers (or a compound trigger that implements multiple triggers if you're using 11.2).  You'd need a package that declared a collection of `emp_id` values.  You'd need a before statement trigger that initialized that collection.  You'd need a row-level trigger that inserted the `:new.emp_id` values into that package's collection.  And then you'd need an after statement trigger that iterates through the collection and does the check.  That's a lot of moving pieces that you'd have to implement, debug, and maintain.

But it's actually worse than just a proliferation of code-- you'd need to implement your own serialization mechanism as well.  Otherwise, assuming you allow multiple users in your system, it would be possible for two sessions to both insert a row with the same `emp_id`, have each session's checks succeed, and then have both sessions commit leaving you with duplicate values in your table.  That means that you would also need to implement some logic that would ensure that only one session could be inserting data into this table at any point in time.  That, in turn, will radically decrease the scalability of your system and will very likely lead to maintenance issues where sessions hold a lock, blocking everyone else in the system, until the DBA finds and kills them.

Comment: Until the DBA finds and kills the session, or the developer?

Comment: @AlexPoole - Depends on the DBA and what sort of mood he or she is in.  Either option works.

Answer (score 3):

I think you're missing an `OF`

```
BEFORE 
INSERT OR UPDATE OF emp_id 
ON emp_mb
```

By the way, you could just use a UNIQUE constraint, couldn't you ?